# Bulk expired domains checker

Tags: python, python-sockets

I want to check a list of domains in a text file, whether they are registered or not. If they are not registered, I want to write those domains in another file. I wrote the code in python, but the main issue is that many registered domains are shown as not registered. Here is my code

```
import sys
import socket
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def domainChecker(url):
    url=url.strip()
    try:    
        socket.gethostbyname_ex(url)
        return None
    except:
        return url

def main():
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    urls=[]
    with open('domains.txt') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            urls.append(line)
    results = pool.map(domainChecker, urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    myfile = open('result.txt', 'w')
    for url in results:
        myfile.write("%s\n" % url)
    myfile.close    
    print("Completed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Grab one of the wrong domains and investigate the problem. What kind of exception is thrown for that example?

Comment: Please add the error you see, without that it cannot be Investigated further.